In which sequence does the html iframe's sandbox parameters are validated?
I am using iframe with sandbox mode as below. I am not getting why, when I keep sandbox="", I get the errors on console only related to "allow-scripts" parameter.
What about other parameters like "allow-same-origin"?
What is the sequence in which they're validated?
Are the next parameters ignored if previous ones are missing?
Where is the official documentation for this??
<iframe data-refapp="true" sandbox="" loading="lazy" title="Amazon" id="random_id"
 src="https://dudeism.com/ordination-form/" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
class="rfp-iframe_dynamic_E18258CF605E4F9CBD76F7F050E5C066"> </iframe>

